# How can I get PowerApps to see SharePoint Online multi-select Choice field values?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps

I have a PowerApps form connected to a SharePoint Online list.  My SharePoint list titled "Log" has a multi-select Choice column named "Service", which appears in PowerApps as a combo-box.  The user can select 1 or more "Services" from this combo-box.  Based on the selection of services, a number of related "Agencies" should appear in a Gallery on the form.  The Agencies are defined against each Service in the Services list.

Log List:

- Services: Multi-select lookup

Service List:

- Title
- Agency (Multi-select Choice, all possible agencies for this Service)

While I can get the selected services from the combo box, the problem is that I am unable to retrieve the values from the Agency multi-select Choice field in the same list.  What I have tried is to get the selected Services from the dcvServices control (into SelectedServices) and then collect the related Agency values (into AvailableAgencies) during the OnSelect of the Service dropdown:

```
ClearCollect(SelectedServices, Filter([@Service], Title in dcvServices.SelectedItems.Value));
ClearCollect(AvailableAgencies, SelectedServices.Agency);
```

When I try to hook up my Gallery control to the AvailableAgencies collection, I can't quite getthe Agency values to display.  I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's walk through an example, which should shed some light on this problem. If my Service list has these values:

[image: Example services]

And the services 1 and 4 are selected in the combo box:

[image]

Then the expression `ClearCollect(SelectedServices, Filter(Service, Title in dcvServices.SelectedItems.Value))` will assign to the SelectedServices collections two items (Service1, Service 4), each of them having a *list of agencies* associated with it.

If we try to collect the agencies in a separate collection as is, with the expression `ClearCollect(AvailableAgencies, SelectedServices.Agency)`, you will not have the individual agencies in the collection; instead, you will have two records, each of them with a collection itself:

```
[
  Agency: [ { Value: "Agency 1" }, { Value: "Agency 2" }, { Value: "Agency 3" } ],
  Agency: [ { Value: "Agency 1" }, { Value: "Agency 4" }, { Value: "Agency 7" } ]
]
```

And if you have this collection in a gallery, and try to display the value of the agency in a label (which requires a single text value), this won't work (as you stated):

```
ThisItem.Agency.Value
```

Because this is not a single text value, but a collection of them (for example, the first item would be the collection of agencies 1,2,3). You could show all values for that specific record using the [Concat function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-concatenate), as shown below:

[image: Concatenating values for each record]

This may not be what you need; if you want all of the *individual* agencies that are associated with the selected services, you will need a different expression:

```
Clear(AvailableAgencies2);
ForAll(
    SelectedServices,
    Collect(AvailableAgencies2, ThisRecord.Agency.Value))
```

And with that you will have the agencies only in your collection:

[image: Agencies only]

Notice that since both service 1 and 4 were associated with the Agency 1, it appears twice. If you don't want that, you can use the [Distinct function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-distinct) to filter any repeated values out:

```
Clear(AvailableAgencies2);
ForAll(
    SelectedServices,
    Collect(AvailableAgencies2, ThisRecord.Agency.Value));
ClearCollect(AvailableAgencies3, Distinct(AvailableAgencies2, Value))
```

And that should give you the list of unique agencies associated with the selected services.